# Do these rationalization substitutions to solve logarithmic inequalities work?

Tags: inequality, logarithms

Thise are lists of rationalization substitutions to solve inequalities.

Left side is $someExpression > 0$, right side is a simpler but 100% equivalent (equivalent inequality $anotherExpression > 0$ having same solutions). Any letter can mean a function (like $f(x)$).

I am **not sure about (1) and (2) from Figure 3** at the very bottom(square means equivalence). Does that work?

Fig.1

[image]

Fig.2
[image]

Fig.3
[image]

[image] means $ >, >=, <, <=$

P.S. *I don't see any problems with all these substitutions, please comment if you see any errors*

More equivivalent substitutions:

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

P.S. Just for the reference in once place (non-logarithmic rationalizing substitutions):

[image]

[image]
[image]